# Why did my desktop background changed and why pictures were opened, if I did nothing to do so?

Tags: macos, desktop

This is what happened:

- My desktop background changed 3 times at different times.

The *change picture (every x time)* option is disabled and I have always had it in that way.

- When I selected a picture to be open, two more pictures were opened too.

I perfectly remember that I only choose **one** picture to be open. As a matter of fact, this event had never happened to me in my life. Also, think about this, what a "coincidence" that the same day that pictures are opened without requesting is the same day that my desktop background changes too.

> There must be a reason because things don't happen just like that.

NOTES.

1. All the time when this happened, my mac didn't have connection to internet.
2. Every once in a while I see a message on the upper RHS (in the corner of the screen) telling me that I should update something related to the system but I always click on later and then the message vanishes.
3. User Allan said that [I am not hacked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384778/is-my-macbook-hacked-or-is-it-just-a-software-bug), then what could possibly have happened?

Please tell me.

I think there must be a reason because things don't happen just like that.

Comment: Please don‘t ask the same question several times. If necessary, edit the original question instead to add details and focus.

Comment: @nohillside but notice the note on the close box "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." And that's what I did

Comment: Your original question is not closed. If the answer you got there doesn't resolve your problem, please revise the question itself to make it more easy for others to understand which problem you want to get help with and what you are looking for in terms of answers.

Comment: @nohillside I have edited my other question and I set a +100 bounty

Comment: If you were *not* connected to the Internet at the time, how could you have possibly been hacked?  You can’t have a hacker connected to your computer while your computer is offline

Comment: @Allan "You can’t have a hacker connected to your computer while your computer is offline" always? Is there _absolute_ **no** possibility  of someone being on my computer while not connected to the internet?

Comment: Tell me, then, how does one connect to to your computer when it's [*offline.*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/offline)

Comment: @Allan Maybe through an "invisible" connection. For example, I've heard that one can be seen through the camera (which is on the upper side, centered) whether the lens light is on or off, intruders  know how to deactivate this light on purpose to make you think that nobody is seeing you. That's why it's recommended to put a stick on the camera. I think Mark Zuckerberg also gave this recommendation

Comment: It was a rhetorical question.  Nobody can connect to your computer and thusly access your camera if you’re offline. There’s no such thing as an “invisible” connection.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same image selected for all Spaces? that would be the simplest explanation, that you don't.

Test by pressing F4 [or FnF4 depending on how your machine prefs are set]. This should zoom all the windows out so you can see them all, but also present a set of you current Spaces at the top of the screen.

If you mouse over those, they will expand to small pictures & unless an app is covering the entire Space, you will be able to see the desktop background for that Space too…

For example…

[image]

All my Spaces are set to the same image, but it's not compulsory.

Comment: The answer to your question is Yes. The same image for all the Spaces

Comment: Actually I usually work in one Space. And when adding another Space, it automatically set the same desktop background to the new Space