# How do I wipe a Mac whose Find My is turned off?

Tags: macbook-pro, find-my-mac

Is there any way to wipe a MacBook Air that has  Find My Mac disabled?

The issue is that my MacBook Air 2018 was showing a symbol X since May’23 after Ventura 13.4 upgrade meaning that the battery needs replacement and was running very slowly with the processor showing 80 % capacity utilisation without any load.Interestingly though diagnostics did not report any issue. The camera stopped working after upgrading to Ventura earlier.

I did some trouble shooting with Mac support and the local Mac book authorised support guys and they advised that the battery needs to be replaced.

Which I did.

Now after doing that within a weeks time the system stopped charging and now would not start.

The support centre is telling that the logic board needs replacement, which does not make sense to me.

Now in MacBook Air the ssd is soldered with the board.

I want to ensure that the memory is wiped clean before replacement.

Better still is there any way to make sure that the logic board has actually failed?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this makes the question much easier to understand. Not sure whether the "Find my mac" part of the title is correct though: Find my Mac can't magically erase a Mac which doesn't boot any longer. So the main question here probably is to figure out how to erase an on-board SSD if the computer doesn't boot any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot track or control (wipe) that device if Find My wasn’t enabled.  In your case, though it’s    likely not necessary.

> The support centre is telling that the logic board needs replacement, which does not make sense to me…Now in MacBook Air the ssd is soldered with the board…I want to ensure that the memory is wiped clean before replacement.

A dead logic board cannot access the SSD nor can the SSD be removed and soldered onto a different logic board with the data in tact.  The T2 chip takes care of this.

#### Do you need a new logic board?

Possibly.  The symptoms you describe are indicative of a power delivery and charging failure which are all handled by the aforementioned T2 (previously the SMC).  However, it could be failures of associated circuitry and not the chip itself.

- Apple and most Apple authorized service centers will simply replace the board and send it off for recycling.  Your data will remain unaccessed and the board will be destroyed/recycled
- Some service center and 3rd party repair shops will likely  use your board as a donor board since these components are very, very hard to source. Once they disassemble it your data is inaccessible
- A malevolent repair shop (authorized or not) could repair your board, even temporarily, and extract the data.  This is unlikely.  The value of the components is worth far more than the time and materials to attempt a repair.  Though not imposible for this scenario to occur, it is improbable.

#### Going Forward…

- **Enable FileValut encryption.** The likely hood of someone gaining access to your data, especially in your particular scenario is almost nil.  Not only would an attacker have to repair your drive, they would have to break the encryption of your drive.
- Enable Find My proactively.  This cannot be enabled retroactively.  Your data is secured with Filevault, but having Find My and the ability to wipe it remotely will turn your Mac into a brick making it useless to bad actors.

(Leaving this here for folks who encounter a lost Mac and looking for steps when Find My isn’t enabled)

However, you need to take the following actions:

- Sign out of iCloud
- Change your iCloud password
- Remove device the list of Trusted Devices
- Report the device missing to law enforcement

See the Apple Support document [If Find My iPhone or Find My iPad isn't enabled on your missing device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211207)

Additionally, see [Macbook (non-M1) was stolen, and the thieves got access to the apple password (not the computer password). No filevault. Can they retrieve passwords?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/459232/119271) for additional info if your Mac was taken while signed in with your Apple password.